# Can more than one developer share the same APNS Certificate?

Tags: ios, notifications, certificate, push

I am a developer in a team. I need to test my application and use APNS. When I download the existing APNS certificate for development and add it to my login keychain, the NWPusher says the keychain does not contain private key.

So should I create a new one and revoke the old development APNS certificate?In case the certificates in the other developer's use become invalid ?

Can I create a new one without revoking the old one?

Any other suggestions would do too.

Comment: Ask your team members for a private key and add it to the keychain.

Comment: can I also create a new one for me and the two certificates work together ?

Comment: not for the same application, as I recall.

Comment: You can create multiple certificates for the same app. Also, I don't understand why you each need a push certificate.. The server uses HTTP2 with JWT tokens for push..

Comment: @Brandon The owner of the certificate is not just available at the moment. Can we both happily use our certificates seperately then ?

Comment: You can both use your certificates.. Why? Apple allows you to create new certificates so that your server can continue to work up until the old certificate expires. When the old one is about to expire, you swap it with a new one some days before.. Yes you can simultaneously use BOTH certificates.